# What is the difference between Bukharin's version of socialism/ Stalinist socialism, and the national socialism created by Hitler?

Tags: ideology, socialism, nazism

We know that Stalin wanted to concentrate on [Socialism in one country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism_in_one_country) and not an international revolution, and the ideology used that time was a very nationalistic version of socialism called Stalinism. So what is the difference between Stalinism in the USSR and the national socialism created by Hitler ?